# Associative Array merge in php

Tags: php

I want to merge array in php. Here I pushed array value to a master array. Here my master array is

```
$master_array = [
  56 => [
    'item_name'=> 'xyz',
    'item_code'=> 56,
  ]
];
```

sub array which I want to push

```
$sub_array = [
  60 => [
    'item_name'=> 'xy',
    'item_code'=> 60,
  ]
];
```

And finally array should be

```
$array = [
  56 => [
    'item_name'=> 'xyz',
    'item_code'=> 56,
  ],
  60 => [
    'item_name'=> 'xy',
    'item_code'=> 60,
  ]
];
```

I tried with

```
array_push( $master_array , $sub_array );
```

But it's always replacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `+` operator: `$array = $master_array + $sub_array;`

```php
$master_array = [
  56 => [
    'item_name'=> 'xyz',
    'item_code'=> 56,
  ]
];

$sub_array = [
  60 => [
    'item_name'=> 'xy',
    'item_code'=> 60,
  ]
];

$array = $master_array + $sub_array;

print_r($array);
```

**The result will be:**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Use php function array_merge()

```
$master_array = [
  56 => [
    'item_name'=> 'xyz',
    'item_code'=> 56,
  ]
];

$sub_array = [
  60 => [
    'item_name'=> 'xy',
    'item_code'=> 60,
  ]
];

$array = array_merge($master_array , $sub_array);
```